# How do I check accuracy within the loop?

Tags: python, psychopy

I am trying to code a function for my experiment which shows 2 labels above a a coloured rectangle in the middle. Subjects has to press either left or right to categorise the colour with one of the labels above.

I would like to code within in the loop that if accuracy = 1, then the experiment should show an info-text saying their choice was correct, and vice versa if accuracy = 0. After they press enter to continue, it should go back to the original loop and then repeat itself.

How do I do that?

```
# make a function for one trial of colour practice
def con1_trial(self):
    global trial
    global key
    trial += 1
    target_colour = random.choice(colours) 

    # show one square with gouloboy colour in top right corner of screen
    col3rec.setFillColor(target_colour)
    col3rec.draw()
    sinij_text.draw()
    boy_text.draw()

    # draw and flip
    win.flip()

    key, test_answer = event.waitKeys(keyList=['right', 'left', 'escape'], timeStamped = True)[0]
    for colour_pair in colour_pairs:
        if test_colour == colours[0] and key == "left":
            accuracy = 1
        elif test_colour == colours[1] and key == "right":
            accuracy = 1
        elif key == 'escape':
            core.quit() 
        else: accuracy = 0

    # records time in ms
    rt = (test_answer - test_start)*1000
    return accuracy, rt
```

Comment: One day people will stop using global variables. I wish I could live long enough to witness that moment of divine grace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the code neat, first define a feedback function somewhere earlier in your script:

```py
feedback_text = visual.TextStim(win)
def show_feedback(feedback):
    # Show feedback on screen
    feedback_text.text = feedback
    feedback_text.draw()
    win.flip()

    # Wait for key
    event.waitKeys()
```

Following your code add something this:

```py
# Show feedback
if accuracy == 1:
    show_feedback('Correct! Well done. Press a key to continue...')
elif accuracy == 0:
    show_feedback('Wrong! Press a key to continue...')
```

... with the correct level of indentation. I always end up having some sort of function to show a message. In `show_feedback` you could also add something to quit the experiment:

```py
key = event.waitKeys()[0]  # get first key pressed
if key == 'escape':
    core.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very useful.

Comment: Although now it completely freezes after I've coded the definition and function in my script...

Answer (score 0):

A trial is defined as picking a color, drawing, waiting for an input, and then recording the answer.
Here's some pseudocode

```
def trial():
    color = random.choice(colours)
    # draw stuff
    # set time start
    # wait for key press
    # check if key press correct
    # print whether they were correct and the time
    if enter pressed: trial()
```